# M1 Mac periodically "freezes" while all apps continue running, but clicking/keyboard inputs no longer register

Tags: macos, apple-silicon

I have an Apple M1 Pro MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2021) running macOS Monterey 12.2.1.

It seems that every once in a while (anywhere from once every few days to once every couple hours), the machine would "freeze" whereby I am suddenly no longer able to click nor type on anything.

However, moving the cursor still works, and *some* gesture commands (such as expose) still work. All running apps continue running in the background: If I am in a zoom call I still can see people's videos and hear their voices, and they can see / hear me just fine. If I am watching a video, the video will continue playing etc.

Everything seems to continue running just fine, and I can even move the cursor around. However no clicks register and no key presses register either. Sometimes when I click, the cursor will "jump" back to a previous location on the screen, only to "jump" back to the new location when I move it around again.

So far I've not been able to find any way to resolve this when it happens other than a hard restart.

Not able to open activity monitor when this happens so no way to check on system resource usage nor force close any apps.

Is there any work around or fix for this?

---

Adding some more details:

1. No bluetooth attachments were connected when this happens
2. No external monitors plugged in

Comment: Are you using a wired or wireless keyboard/mouse? If wireless, is it via Bluetooth?

Comment: Did you checked [this](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/693303) ?

Comment: @PtitXav Isn't that the opposite for the OP th cursor might work but nothing else does, whilst that link is trackpad not working.

Comment: Do you have a external disk attached?

Comment: Did you tried to keep monitor opened in one space so when it happens you can switch to it ? It will use a little cpu usage but you would have it started when needed.

Comment: 1) Am not using any wireless attachments when this happens
2) No external disk attached
3) No external monitors attached

Comment: Yeah I will try to keep a second monitor attached and see if I can just keep activity monitor running on the second screen or something so I can at least see what's going on when this happens. 

I'm traveling for the next few weeks and don't have my external displays with me. Will try when I get back home

Comment: Been a while, but I finally got a chance to keep activity monitor going on a second monitor. When clicking / typing froze again, the activity monitor had no spikes, and CPU / Memory etc were all in reasonable ranges.